# How do I run multiple `cmd.exe /c` commands without getting an error?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm building a solution that needs to execute a dynamically built terminal command cross-platform. This is the command on macOS (actually a single line of text, changed for readability):

```
cat "/path/to/file1.txt" "/path/to/file2.txt" > "/path/to/output.txt" ;
rm "/path/to/file1.txt" ; rm "/path/to/file2.txt"
```

After a bit of research, the equivalent on Windows would be:

```
cmd.exe /c type "C:/path/to/file1.txt" "C:/path/to/file2.txt" > "C:/path/to/output.txt" ;
del "C:/path/to/file1.txt" ; del "C:/path/to/file2.txt"
```

Now, that *seems* to work when I put it in manually in the PowerShell, but I get errors. Note that the concatenation and deletion of the files appears to work, but I'm getting the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing C:/path/to/file1.txt
The system cannot find the file specified.
Error occurred while processing C:/path/to/file2.txt
```

When the Windows version of the command is dynamically built and executed, the concatenation works but the file removal does not, and my guess is it's because of these errors.

What does the Windows version of this need to be in order to work exactly like the macOS version?

(In case you're wondering, this is within a [FileMaker](https://www.filemaker.com/) database that uses the [`BE_ExecuteSystemCommand`](https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205350557-BE-ExecuteSystemCommand) function from the [BaseElements](https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002990887) plugin.)

Comment: "*When the Windows version of the command is dynamically built and executed*" - how is it dynamically built and executed? (and why are you typing command prompt commands into PowerShell?)

Comment: I't built using FileMaker's string manipulation features. The command above (`cmd.exe /c ...`), when executed within FileMaker concatenates the files but doesn't delete them. When the exact same string is pasted into PowerShell (which, as to why I'm using it, to test the command, would welcome a better way if there is one) it works but with the errors. It's executed, both on macOS and Windows, using the `BE_ExecuteSystemCommand` function mentioned above.

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `type asdf ; asdf` - same error you're seeing with the four cannot find / error occurred outputs. Semicolons end a line in bash and PowerShell, but I don't think they do in cmd.exe. From your linked documentation, BE_ExecuteSystemCommand acts like typing at a command line, so you shouldn't need the `cmd /c` part either. Can you do it with three separate calls? Can you put newline `\r\n` characters in the string?

Comment: I'll try it with three calls instead of one. But it does need the `cmd /c` prefix. According to that linked page: "On Windows you need to prefix your command with "cmd.exe /c"."

Comment: Not critical, and generally won't cause an error but your windows directory delimiters are technically backwards too. `C:\Folder\Subfolder\file.ext`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses backslashes, not forward slashes, in path names.  Some commands will allow you to use forward slashes instead, but `del` is not one of them:

```
C:\Users\UoW>del "c:/Users/UoW/test.dat"
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\UoW>del "c:\Users\UoW\test.dat"

C:\Users\UoW>
```

Comment: I also had to separate the commands into three calls instead of one, but otherwise, your solution was what I needed.

Comment: You can use `&` to combine multiple commands into a single one.  Also note that a single `del` command can delete more than one file.

Answer (score 0):

Try staying in PowerShell, try this:

```
Add-Content -Path "C:/path/to/output.txt" -Value (Get-Content "C:/path/to/file1.txt")    
Add-Content -Path "C:/path/to/output.txt" -Value (Get-Content "C:/path/to/file2.txt")    
Remove-Item -Path "C:/path/to/file1.txt"    
Remove-Item -Path "C:/path/to/file2.txt"
```

Comment: I'm only using PowerShell to test the generated command. I'm looking for a single-line equivalent that uses `cmd.exe /c` to the macOS version above. Is there a version of your solution that would allow that?

Comment: I apologize, I missed the part where PowerShell was only used for testing and couldn't be used for production.  To go back to your original cmd.exe method; if you replace the ; in your line with & then it will allow for multiple command execution.  cmd.exe /c type "C:/path/to/file1.txt" "C:/path/to/file2.txt" > "C:/path/to/output.txt" &
del "C:/path/to/file1.txt" & del "C:/path/to/file2.txt" should accomplish what you're trying to do in one line.